# Bianchi Bike - Help Identifying Model

Tags: road-bike, frames, identify-this-bike, mechanical, road

I'm looking at buying a Bianchi bike, I was wondering if anyone can tell from this image the type of bike, model and year. The owner bought it 2nd hand so doesn't have much info. Any assistance would be great

[image]

Comment: I would point out that it's not a very high spec one and old style cable routing and components, so don't pay too much for it just to get the name

Answer (score 2):

Some observations:

- Its an `80s bike at best - the downtube shifters and severe rake on the forks show its no newer.   The cranks appear to not be cottered, so it is newer than the 70s.
- The current rider is either too small for this bike or has a particularly forward and aggressive body position. 
   The saddle is quite far forwards, meaning the seatpost/saddle clamp is reversed with the bolt to the front.
   Also the bars are droopy and look like someone has hung them like track bike bars.  The sides should be more horizontal and the brake levers should be lower on the bars.  As pictured the rider will put more weight on the web of the thumb, and more weight on the front of the bike.
- I bet braking is horrible with the hoods being so low - one would struggle to get a good grip on the brake levers from the hoods.  Though if it was always ridden in the drops might make more sense.
- The pedals are flat MTB pedals, maybe with retaining pins.  This is anachronistic for this bike, but function beats form and you need some kind of pedals.
- Can't see much of the drive train, but the chonking big chain guard on the front derailleur is typical of Bike Boom designs from the late 70s and early 80s.   I see the front derailleur cable passes over the bottom bracket and appears to be outer housing.  So its likely one of those unusual front derailleur setups.
- Do check if the tyres are "622" size, not the older 630 size.  The rims appear to be aluminium which is good and implies 622.  An 80s bike could easily have steel rims which are poorer at braking and heavier, but tend to be 630mm.  This number will be written on the sidewall of the tyre, along with the width in millimetres, so "622-25"   or   "25-622"

---

The seat tube has a Bianchi decal that is more than 90 degrees off horizontal.  That's kinda weird and it might be a stylistic design, or an error by whoever slapped "desirable" Bianchi decals on whatever frame it is.

Valuations are considered off-topic, but remember you're looking for overall condition and wear too.  A bike that needs lots of parts is worth less than the same bike with wear remaining in the components.

The tubes appear straight in the photo, and the frame looks in decent proportions.  There's something about a horizontal top tube that is just "right" to my eye.   I like it !

Answer (score 2):

After spending a good bit of time searching with google images i've come to the conclusion this bike is probably either fake or badly restored.

There are many [images](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=white%201980%27s%20bianchi&sxsrf=ALiCzsaEjtELCjwYQRDp6LPtC4wFqTdOcw:1659533219554&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJlK2A46r5AhXQS0EAHYWRCWwQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1549&bih=1015&dpr=1) of white 1980's Bianchi's.

None of them have a fork curve as extreme as we see here.
None of them seem to have this style of cable routing for the front derailleur.
The images also show that the decals on the seat tube of this bike are upside down.

Comment: I disagree: [this picture](https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzY5WDEwMjQ=/z/g6wAAOSwx9takFlt/$_59.JPG) has a similar fork curve, as does [this one](https://files.bikeindex.org/uploads/Pu/59135/large_IMG_4516.jpg) and the "Rekord" model in [this 1973 catalog](https://velobase.com/Resource_Tools/DownloadFile.aspx?Path=%2fCatalogScans%2fBianchi1973_ital.pdf&FileName=Bianchi1973_ital.pdf) (p. 4).  The 2nd looks like it has the same derailleur cable routing.  I agree that the decal is upside down, but that could be a restoration error.

Comment: @DavidW The fork curve seems way less (or perhaps a steeper head angle) in your first link.  The 1973 "Rekord" does indeed look very similar, but this bike is white with 80's decals.  This is why I included the option of a bad restoration in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a bianchi portofino that looks similar [image: here's mine]

Comment: how are the gear cables routed? also your decals and logos are properly oriented. Nice bike btw.

Comment: @Noise The cables run down the downtube and there's a cable guide by the crank. Then the rear runs along the chain stay. And thanks! I actually got the bike free as a hand me down from a friend and it got me really into cycling!